# PHP compatible regex to grab everything between ticks

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab `BaseItemCode` from the following phrase:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`BaseItemCode`) REFERENCES `BaseItems`
```

This is what I currently have, but I don't know how to exclude the characters '`', '(', and ')'

```
(?<=FOREIGN KEY)\s+\K(\(`[A-Za-z0-9]+`\))
```

It grabs `` (`BaseItemCode`) ``

---

As per Marty's comment, this gave me:

```
(?<=FOREIGN KEY)\s+\K\(`([A-Za-z0-9]+)`\)
```

Which retrieves 'BaseItemCode' in group 2.

---

Ah!  I got one more step ahead, the following grabs exactly what I need:

```
(?<=FOREIGN KEY \(`)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=`\))
```

Comment: Don't put them in the capturing group (take them out of the `()` in your regex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your regex to:

```
(?<=FOREIGN KEY)\s+\K(\(`([A-Za-z0-9]+)`\))
```

Group 2 will contain `BaseItemCode`

If you just want to match `BaseItemCode`, without using groups, use this regex:

```
(?<=FOREIGN KEY\s\(`)\w+(?=`\))
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a step closer - is there a way that I can do this without groups?

Comment: Nothing, really.  It was more of a curiosity.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Zaemz, you can use this regex **(?<=FOREIGN KEY\s\(`)\w+(?=`\))** if you want without groups

Comment: Nice to see another fan of `\K`, +1 for that. I've been noticing your efficient regex. :) Gosh it can get crowded in these regex questions.